# Which wiki system is better suited?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, web-applications, wiki

For my website and coming all sites from now on, I want to have a wiki system, which can -

1) Support internalization easily, that is the wiki has a system to serve contents based on the language user selects. For example keeping 'en' as default, the wiki has to be able to serve other language articles, if a different language version exists. If i have a F.A.Q. page in english and spanish, changing language would server appropriate content.

2) It should be light weight and easy to install.

3) Only I can edit contents, others have no edit option. The wiki system has to have an easy way to switch off editing by guests. All edits are admin only.

I'm considering MediaWiki, but I wish to know if there is a better wiki system agreed by experienced and veterans. :)

Thanks,
Anjan

Comment: If you want multilingualism, in MediaWiki just install MLEB. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MLEB

Answer (score 1):

Wikis are tools for groups and individuals to collaborate in content. **If you simply want version control for your pages**, Wordpress with a multi-language plugin is certainly a better choice. Nowadays Wordpress is a fully featured CMS, not just a blog engine.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/multilanguage

- It's far easier to configure than Mediawiki
- It has comments by default
- It has more plugins than Mediawiki, and more free templates as well
- You can add flash and javascript to individual pages

In my opinion the only thing in which Mediawiki can be better is as a collaboration tool.